# Subprocess.py errors

Tags: android, python, subprocess

I want complie game to android but...

I have problem with Subprocess.py

I get the following error messages:

```
File "D:\Documents and Settings\Kiraler\Pulpit\renpy-apk-6.13.7.1\build.py", line 321, in <module> 
make_package<args>
File D:\Documents and Settings\Kiraler\Pulpit\renpy-apk-6.13.7.1\build.py", line 201, in make_package 
subprocess.call<[ANDROID, "update", "project", "-p", '.', '-t', android-8]

File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen<*popenargs, **kwargs>.wait<> 

File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite>

File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
startupinfo>

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Module:

```
# Update the project to a recent version.
subprocess.call([ANDROID, "update", "project", "-p", '.', '-t', 'android-8'])

shutil.rmtree("assets")

if args.assets:
    shutil.copytree(args.assets, "assets")

else:
    os.mkdir("assets")

if renpy:
    shutil.copytree("engine-assets/common", "assets/common")
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: try with `subprocess.call([ANDROID, "update", "project", "-p", '.', '-t', 'android-8'], shell=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the problem is that the `ANDROID` variable in the code isn't a fully qualified path name to the binary you want to use.

Hence, the comment that suggests to use `shell=True` looks like an appropriate one as long as you've got your `PATH` environment variable properly configured so that `ANDROID` can be found.

If that's not the case, you can:

- Provide the full path in the `ANDROID` variable
- Use the `env` parameter when calling to `subprocess.Popen` to provide your own customized `PATH` environment variable to the subprocess. For more information, 
  please have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).